# Using assignment instead of equality for constant object values

Tags: java, equals, assign

Given a definition like the following

```
public interface Type
{
    public static final Type NULL = new Type() { public void method() {} };

    public void method();
}
```

is there any case of an equality check error if all code that creates objects from implementations of `Type`, uses (and checks for equality) the `Type.NULL` value mentioned above?

For example, assuming declarations like

```
public Type calculate() {...}
Type t = calculate();
```

the return value of `calculate()` could be `Type.NULL` whenever null is the result and instead of checking

```
if (t == null)
```

one would check

```
if (t == Type.NULL)
```

thus making the return type of `calculate()` always non-null.

(The question is not about whether this is the best practice to follow, it just tries to verify that there can not be any accuracy issues with this approach.)

Comment: You can check for equality with `t == Type.NULL` as long as all code that could return a null object returns `Type.NULL` rather than creating its own version of it. By the way, your definition does not compile.

Comment: Minor typo (the parentheses), thanks for spotting it. I agree with your comment, so +1 :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of OO design, I would distinguish between two situations.

1. You want to model that **nothing** has been returned, the variable has not defined value. In this case I would use `null`. I cannot see any advantage of using `if (t == Type.NULL)` instead of `if (t == null)`.
2. You want to model an **empty operation/value** has been returned, the variable is defined, but the value is a kind of a "zero". In that case I would use your solution, but I would not call it `NULL`, but rather `VOID` or `EMPTY` or similar based on your business logic. This is preferable not because you want to use `if (t == Type.NULL)` instead of `if (t == null)`, but because you want to **not use any if at all** - you may just use the variable as it contains a meaningful (however empty) value.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a concrete `NullType` subclass of type:

```
class NullType extends Type {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your method can return a `NullType` instance, so the check would be:

```
if (t instanceof NullType)
```

It might make sense to have `NullType` be a singleton as well.

Comment: Hmmm... The instanceof check is slower than the NULL check and NULL is a singleton anyway. A reasonable answer, though, so +1.

Comment: @PNS Please, please do not worry about the speed difference between `==` and `instanceof`; the difference is completely and utterly negligible.

Comment: Sure, but then, if instanceof was the way to go, no NullType is needed. One can do instanceof in any Type return value and if false is returned, have the same result, since null values return false on instanceof.

Comment: @PNS That's true, but returning `null` allows for the possibility of a null pointer exception somewhere down the road, whereas using a `NullType` instance does not.

Comment: Yes, which is the motivation for the Type.NULL value, too. :-)

Comment: @PNS Yes indeed, I was presenting the `NullType` approach as a simple alternative. Personally, it's the approach I would use since it allows for greater flexibility in the future.

Comment: I don't think you should use *meta-information* for a regular checks on the business logic levels. It's kind of a violation of the OO paradigm. And using `instanceof` is considered as reflexion.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: `instanceof` provides run-time access to meta-information about objects. It is in fact using reflection. In my opinion this should not be used for checking of something has a logical NULL value.

Comment: This is true. Personally, I prefer having a special value, as per the example I published..